# Unexpected Identifier Expected Error

Tags: java

I am a competitive C++ programmer who recently started to learn Java. 
I tried writing a program for problem 556A on Codeforces (an easy problem) to practice, but came across an <identifier> expected problem, even though the code was short and nothing was outside of the "main" function.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class 556A {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );
        int len;
        len=s.next();
        char in;
        int n0=0;
        int n1=0;

        for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
            in=s.next();
            if (in=='0') n0++;
            else n1++;
        }
        int x=abs(n0-n1);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class name is invalid, it may not begin with a number. rename it to Exercise556A

Comment: Class name is invalid

Comment: Some remarks on your code: you may want to either write whitespaces on both sides of all binary operators or on none of them, but not mix them.  Same goes for parameter parentheses. Also while you can neglect the braces of an `if`- or `else`-body if it is a one-liner, this is generally regarded as bad practice since it hinders readability and faciliates bugs.

Comment: And you say you are a competitive C++ programmer, but C++ won't allow you to write `class 556A` either.

Comment: I never wrote problems inside classes :P. C++ doesn't require you to do so.